# iPad SQLite database

Tags: ipad

Is it possible to create a table in SQLite which has more than 25000 rows...? I would like to create an iPad application which will work in association with a web application, the web application use MS SQL as back end. Is it possible to fetch large amount of data from MS SQL database..?, If it possible up to how much amount of data can fetch...?

Answer (score 0):

a table in sqlite is limited to 2^64 rows but you'd hit the disk space problems way before that

i've used sqlite on a table having just over 2 million rows which is the most i've put in one

so it's mostly limited by the disk space available

but indexes on a table cost about 0.1 second per 10k inserts per index so really don't put more then is required i tested this with a table of 750 columns and 750 indexes it took hours to put in test data but i was testing extremes most tables will not have that many columns